# MapReduce not working in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, mapreduce, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePHP 3.x, my application has add/edit pages, in edit action I'm using this code.

```
 $patient = $this->Patients->get($patientId);
```

to get record of patient.

Now I want to modify value of some field after find operation, let say I want to convert `dob` field (date_of_birth) into different date format, in CakePHP 2.x it's possible in `afterFind` callback but in CakePHP 3.x [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods) in last paragraph it state that,

> If you need to modify the results after they have been fetched you should use a [Modifying Results with Map/Reduce](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce) function to modify the results. The map reduce features replace the ‘afterFind’ callback found in previous versions of CakePHP.

I had also use `MapReduce` but it won't work for me.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Please be more specific as to what _exactly_ the problem is with your attempts.

Answer (score 3):

Map/reduce is kind of an overkill for such a simple task, I'd suggest to use a result formatter instead, ie `Query::formatResults()`.

In order to use any of this, ie a mapper/reducer or a formatter, you must use `Table::find()` instead of `Table::get()`, as the latter doesn't return a query, but the result, and the options do not support mappers/reducers or formatters.

However, depending on where you need the formatted value, a helper, a virtual field, or just formatting when necessary might be the better option.

Anyways, here's a basic example:

```
$patient = $this->Patients
    ->find();
    ->where([
        'id' => $patientId
    ])
    ->formatResults(function($results) {
        /* @var $results \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface */
        return $results->map(function($row) {
            // note that now `dob` is a string!
            $row['dob'] = $row['dob']->i18nFormat('dd. MMMM yyyy');
            return $row;
        });
    })
    ->firstOrFail();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Creating Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**
- **[API > \Cake\Datasource\QueryTrait::formatResults()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.QueryTrait.html#_formatResults)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\Time::i18nFormat](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.I18n.Time.html#_i18nFormat)**